# I can't install python libraries with sudo easy_install3 on ev3dev

Tags: python, opencv, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I tried to install specific libraries on ev3dev using sudo easy_install3. But it doesnt't let me do this. Whatever library I tried to install it always writes the same. For example here I tried to install opencv

```
sudo easy_install3 pyopencv
Searching for pyopencv
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyopencv/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyopencv/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pyopencv' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for pyopencv
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pyopencv')
```

I tried to write different names of the same library and I tried to install other libraries, but it always writes the same thing.

Comment: Does this computer have access to the internet? it seems not.

Comment: As @Dr.Snoopy mentioned look at this line `Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyopencv/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!`, pypi.python.org not known

Comment: Well, I'm am connected to ev3dev with SSH terminal in Visual Studio Code and my computer has internet connection. Besides, I was able to update libraries, so I don't think I have problems with the internet

Comment: The device you are connected to does not have internet access (the LEGO Mindstorms).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes, but I'm using SSH terminal on my computer to install, so that is not a problem

Comment: SSH does not transfer your internet connection! The error literally means no internet access (Name or service not known).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy but if I don't have internet why I am able to update libraries using other methods like sudo apt-get update?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Comment: I can't use pip

Comment: 'sudo apt-get install python3-pip' doesn't works. it gives me this: '''Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate'''